# Prolog - Einstein Riddle

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I'm trying to solve the Einstein Riddle using Prolog. I'm sorry for my English. The task is:

- In the block of flats is 5 flats. (ground floor a 1., 2., 3., 4. floor)
- Family Mullerovi have 4 children.
- An administrator lives on the middle floor.
- Mrs. Meierova pays for her flat 60 crowns less than a doctor on 3. floor.
- Family living on the hightest floor have 5 children.
- Family Kernovi have 1 child than teacher.
- Mr Kaufmann works as a sales representative.
- The teacher pays for her flat 1740 crowns.
- On the hightest floor janitor lives.
- The doctor pays for his flat 1800 crowns.
- In the flat, which costs 1760 crowns, arent any children.
- On the 2.floor the family have twice more children than family on the 3.floor.
- Mr Hanz lives directly above family Kernovi.
- In the flat under the janitor live 2 children.
- Mullerovi pay for their flat 1770 crowns.
- The roof flat is cheaper 10 crowns than then ground floor.
- Sales representative pays 30 crowns more than janitor does.

My code looks like, I don't know how to solve problems with hire:

```
person('Name', 'Job','Children','Hire','Floor').

houses(Hs):-
   length(Hs),
   member(person(mullerovi,_,4,1770,_),Hs),
   member(person(_,administrator,_,_,2),Hs),
   member(person(_,doctor,_,1800,_),Hs),
   pays_less(person(_,doctor,_,Hire,_),person('Meinova',_,_,Hire-60,_),Hs),
   member(person(_,_,5,_,4),Hs),
   have_one_children_less(person('Kernovi',_,Children-1,_,_),person(_,teacher,Children,_,_),Hs),
   member(person('Kaufmann','Sales representative',_,_,_),Hs),
   member(person(_,teacher,_,1740,_),Hs),
   member(person(_,janitor,_,_,4),Hs),
   member(person(_,_,0,1760,_),Hs),
   have_2x_children(
         person(_,_,2*Children,_,2),
         person(_,_,Children,_,3),Hs),
   lives_above(person('Hanz',_,_,_,_),person('Kernovi',_,_,_,_),Hs),
   lives_above(person(_,janitor,_,_,_),person(_,_,2,_,_),Hs),
   pays_more(
         person(_,_,_,Hire+10,4),
         person(_,_,_,Hire,'Ground floor'),Hs),
   pays_more(
         person(_,'Sale representative',_,Hire+30,_),
         person(_,janitor,_,Hire,_),Hs).
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: You're making the assumption that prolog will arithmetically evaluate `Hire+10`. It doesn't. It's trying to unify against a term in the form of `X+Y`. Prolog does structural evaluation, not arithmetic.

Comment: Do you mean to create a new rule? I'm new to Prolog.

Comment: `length(Hs),` makes no sense. You really need to put more effort into it first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Einstein Riddle using Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816529/einstein-riddle-using-prolog)

Comment: @lurker - It's close to being a duplicate, but there is a little more complexity here that isn't covered in the other question.

Comment: @WillNess why delete it?

Comment: @WillNess so you are starting your own CLP-implementation :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Einstein Riddle with List of terms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743498/einstein-riddle-with-list-of-terms)

Answer (score 0):

*"In the block of flats is 5 flats"* translates as `length(Hs,5)`.

Then, `pays_less( person(_,doctor,_,Hire,_), person('Meinova',_,_,Hire-60,_),Hs)` is undefined; it ought to be

```
.....
member( person(_,doctor,_,Hire,_), Hs), 
member( person('Meinova',_,_,Hire2,_), Hs), 
.....
Hire2 is Hire-60,  
.....
```

or something like that.

Acquaint yourself with [`is/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) operator and its preconditions. `B=80, A = B-60` succeeds, unifying `A` with `-(80,60)`. You want `B=80, A is B-60` which succeeds and unifies `A` with `20` (but would fail if `B` were not yet a numerical expression).

The line `Hire2 is Hire-60,` should be placed as high as possible in the predicate, for maximal efficiency.

Comment: Rather `when( ( ground(Hire), ground(Hire2) ), Hire2 =:= Hire-60 )`